# Space between each character in python

Tags: python

I need a simple python code that lets you enter text and shows it with space between each character.

I have made something like this and it works but now I don't know how to make it with spaces

```
text = input("text: ")
print(f"{text}")
```

Comment: put this below the first line text = ' '.join([ch for ch in text])

Comment: @DogukanLevendoglu - even simpler: `' '.join(list(text))`

Comment: @PM77-1 - even simpler: `'  '.join(text)`

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input("text: ")
text = ' '.join(list(text))
print(text)
```

Comment: @Atro you need to accept the answer. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you don't know how

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input("enter text here")
words=text.split()
output=""
for word in words:
    for letter in word:
        output = output + letter + " "
print(output)
```

Comment: Produces trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are looking for the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of a string. It takes an iterable and concatenates it together using the string as separator. As a string is an iterable itself you can simply do

```
' '.join('Hello')
>>> H e l l o
```